# Reference to ruined pizza in 'Inside Out'

Tags: reference, inside-out

In *Inside Out* there's the following dialogue (as quoted here from [its IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2096673/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu)):

> Anger: [seeing slices of pizza with only broccoli on top]
>
> Anger: Congratulations San Francisco, you've ruined Pizza! First the Hawaiians, and now YOU!

I don't live in San Francisco or Hawaii, so I didn't understand the reference. Do people from San Francisco or Hawaii make pizza with ridiculous ingredients? Yes, pizza with only broccoli is... not pizza, I suppose you could find that type of 'pizza' in some places there, but he is refering to  Hawaiians. Why?

Comment: "Turns out, according to the Inside Out production team, the pizzeria is based on Arizmendi, with a collection of co-op bakeries in San Francisco and the East Bay." They do make one type of pizza per day, always vegetarian. http://blog.sfgate.com/sfmoms/2015/07/15/an-inside-out-tour-of-san-francisco-pixar-movie-locations-around-town/#photo-663890

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Anger is most likely referring to the toppings on a "[Hawaiian Pizza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_pizza)"... This refers only to the toppings on the pizza, not to any specific type of crust.

If you ask just about any pizza shop for "Hawaiian", you'll get a pizza with Canadian bacon (or ham) and pineapple on it.

The name is likely from the inclusion of the pineapple, though the Wikipedia article claims it was invented in Canada.

Many people love this pizza but many people detest it, clearly, Anger is in the latter group.

Here's this pizza as offered by Little Caesars:

[image: Little Caesar's Hula Hawaiian]

Comment: Flagged as spam for blatant Little Caesars advertizement! You work for them or what? ;-P

Comment: Good answer and accepted but doesn't exactly touch on the San Francisco part. San Francisco is commonly seen as a place where people are trying to healthy, environmentally friendly, and generally liberal (in the American sense). So if someone ruins perfectly good junk food like pizza by trying to make it healthy with broccoli, it's typical to assume that person lives in San Francisco. It's not clear where broccoli on pizza actually got started, but one of the first chains to make it widely available was Pizzaria Uno, which is actually from Chicago.

Comment: I stand corrected, it is widely seen that "gourmet" pizza with unusual toppings (like broccoli) was started in San Francisco: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California-style_pizza

Comment: Broccoli on pizza is doubly terrible. First, it tastes bad; second, it's impossible to pick off cleanly.

Answer (score 7):

As @Catija has explained the Hawaiian part, the San Fransisco part is simply in reference to the events of the movie. The Pizza shop near the new house ***ONLY*** serves Broccoli Pizza. Riley is understandably enraged/disgusted/scared/saddened by that. Hence Anger's widely stereotyping hyperbole.

We also learn later on that Broccoli is literally seen as one of Riley's worst fears in her subconscious. The sight of Broccoli Pizza has tainted the **very idea of Pizza for Riley**.

Riley likely has never hear Broccoli Pizza anywhere sane people would serve pizza, so she makes the immediate connection of San Fransisco with ruining Pizza. On the same vein, Anger is blaming Hawaiians for ruining Pizza, when it's a Canadian invention. It is, like all of Anger's actions, a gut reaction. Not thought out. Impulsive.

Comment: It's been a while since I saw it but I have a difficult time believing that the pizza shop **only** serves broccoli pizza... Is that actually in there?

Comment: Riley ' s mom says it outright. `What kind of pizza place only serves one kind of pizza? Must be a SF thing, shiver` @catija damn hippies

Comment: The SF Bay Area is a trendsetter for food, so be on the lookout for pizza innovations coming your way!  ;)